# How do we understand the Word-Count sample of Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I'm just learning Apache Flink and here is the Word Count sample:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/getting-started/tutorials/local_setup.html

I works but I have something that can't understand clearly.

Flink have three parts: `JobManager`, `TaskManager` and `JobClient`. As my understanding, the java code of the class `SocketWindowWordCount` should be a part of `JobClient`, this class should send what it asks to do to the `JobClient` then the `JobClient` can send the tasks to the `JobManager`.

Am I right?

If I'm right, I don't know which part of code in the file `SocketWindowWordCount.java` is responsible to send what it asks to do to the `JobClient`.

Is listening on the port also a part of the task which will be sent to the `JobManager` then to `TaskManager`?

```
// get input data by connecting to the socket
DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", port, "\n");

// parse the data, group it, window it, and aggregate the counts
DataStream<WordWithCount> windowCounts = text
    .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, WordWithCount>() {
        @Override
        public void flatMap(String value, Collector<WordWithCount> out) {
            for (String word : value.split("\\s")) {
                out.collect(new WordWithCount(word, 1L));
            }
        }
    })
    .keyBy("word")
    .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(1))
    .reduce(new ReduceFunction<WordWithCount>() {
        @Override
        public WordWithCount reduce(WordWithCount a, WordWithCount b) {
            return new WordWithCount(a.word, a.count + b.count);
        }
    });

// print the results with a single thread, rather than in parallel
windowCounts.print().setParallelism(1);
```

Is all of the codes above a part of the task?

In a word, I kind of understand the architecture of Flink but I want to know more details about how the `JobClient` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program itself is the `JobClient` from the architectural point of view. In particular, you have dependencies on the `JobClient` that are used when you execute the `DataStream`.

All of your code is the task definition that gets serialized and sent to the `JobManager`, which distributes it to the `TaskManager`.

You left out the "most" important part of the program

> env.execute("Socket Window WordCount");

That is actually triggering the `JobClient` to package the `DataStream` program and send it to the configured `JobManager`.